# How to filter HP ALM defects using REST API?

Tags: rest, api, hp-alm

I am not able to apply filters to the defects list. Is there a way to get the filtered defects list using REST API ?

```
qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/defects/259
```

Above URL gives me details about the defect 259. 
How to get all defects having `Status= {Assigned,Open,SIT-Ready,UAT-Ready,Rejected} and detected-in-rel = Sprint1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `query` parameter into your URL.
Check [Filtering Section of official docs](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html#REST_API_Tech_Preview/General/Filtering.html) for details

Answer (score 0):

To complete Sergi's answer, with a query parameter it should look like that:

```
qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/defects?query=
```

Followed by your query [url encoded](https://www.url-encode-decode.com/).

In your case, regarding HP ALM format, your query is {Status[Assigned or Open or SIT-Ready or UAT-Ready or Rejected];detected-in-rel[Sprint1]}

Which gives, once url encoded:

```
qcbin/rest/domains/{domain}/projects/{project}/defects?query=%7BStatus%5BAssigned%20or%20Open%20or%20SIT-Ready%20or%20UAT-Ready%20or%20Rejected%5D%3Bdetected-in-rel%5BSprint1%5D%7D
```